# Writing composable asynchronous monads from ffi

Tags: purescript

Right now I have an async function that works something like this:

```
  foo = do 
     ayncGetNumber "/numberLocation" \a -> 
        (trace <<< show) a
```

but this callback style is not composable (to my understanding), i would like it to work like this

```
  foo = do 
     a <- ayncGetNumber "/numberLocation"
     (trace <<< show) a
```

or

```
  foo = ayncGetNumber "/numberLocation" >>= show >>> trace
```

But I can't figure out how to escape from the callback and make it composable.

Comment: I think what would be very benefical here would be giving the type of `asyncGetNumber`. However, it seems that what you want is for your `Monad` to be parameterized over whatever `a` is, rather than include a function with an `a` argument in its construction. If that makes sense.

Comment: Also, if that's not possible, you might want to look into `ContT` https://github.com/purescript-contrib/purescript-transformers/blob/master/docs/Module.md#module-controlmonadconttrans

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to consider using the continuation monad transformer `ContT` from the `purescript-transformers` package.

The definition of `ContT` in that package is given as

```
newtype ContT r m a = ContT ((a -> m r) -> m r)
```

If you set `r` to be `Unit`, and `m` to be `Eff eff`, you get something which looks a bit like the type of `asyncGetNumber` inside the constructor:

```
(a -> Eff eff Unit) -> Eff eff Unit
```

Now, making sure `eff` contains the effect you need, you should be able to wrap up your 
`asyncGetNumber` function for use in `ContT`:

```
asyncGetNumberCont :: ContT Unit (Eff SomeEffects) Number
asyncGetNumberCont = ContT $ \callback -> 
  asyncGetNumber "/numberLocation" callback
```

or just

```
asyncGetNumberCont = ContT $ asyncGetNumber "/numberLocation"
```

Note that the argument to `ContT` takes the callback as an argument.

You can now compose asynchronous computations in series using do notation:

```
do n <- asyncGetNumberCont
   m <- asyncGetNumberCont
   return (n + m)
```

You can even create an applicative functor which wraps `ContT` and supports parallel composition of asynchronous computations. You might also be interested in the `purescript-node-thunk` package which provides this sort of functionality out of the box.

*Edit*: Another option is to create your own `ContT`-like type using a foreign type, distinct from `Eff`. You might do this as follows:

```
-- Ignore effects to keep things simple
-- The runtime representation of 'Async a' is a function which takes a callback,
-- performs some side effects an returns.
foreign import data Async :: * -> *

-- Make an async computation from a function taking a callback
foreign import makeAsync 
  "function makeAsync(f) {\
  \  return function(k) {\
  \    f(function(a) {\
  \      return function() {\
  \        k(a)();\
  \      };\
  \    })();\
  \  };\
  \}" :: forall a eff. ((a -> Eff eff Unit) -> Eff eff Unit) -> Async a

-- Now we need to define instances for Async, which we can do using FFI
-- calls, for example:
foreign import fmapAsync
  "function fmapAsync(f) {\
  \  return function (comp) {\
  \    return function (k) {\
  \      comp(function(a) {\
  \        k(f(a));\
  \      });
  \    };\
  \  };\
  \}" :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> Async a -> Async b

instance functorAsync :: Functor Async where
  (<$>) = fmapAsync
```

and so on. This gets cumbersome quickly since you're essentially repeating the implementation of `ContT`.

In addition, without rewrite rule support in the compiler, there is no way to get the inlined binds like you would get with `Eff`.

Comment: That is really cool, and I will definitely use `ContT` in the future, but really I want to know how to write into ffi in such a way as to composable out of the box without having to transform it afterward.

Comment: It's not possible for `Eff` to express non-synchronous control flow, which is what you want. Every expression of type `Eff eff a` is required to perform its side effects and return its result immediately. This is what allows the compiler to generate efficient code for binds in the `Eff` monad.

Comment: So is its not possible to create a function from the ffi that defines asynchronous computation in this way?

Comment: Not using `Eff`. You could define your own foreign type which took a callback at runtime, but its binds would not be inlined by the compiler. Maybe when rewrite rules get implemented, something like what you want will be possible.

Comment: Thank you so much, being trapped in the callback was killing my >>= >>> >=> flow.

Comment: Dang I am getting `Cannot unify Control.Monad.Eff.Eff with Control.Monad.Cont.Trans.ContT Prelude.Unit` though the `ContT`ed function compiled just fine. Do I need to document ContT in the function that calls this function?

Comment: You will need to run the computation in `ContT` using `runContT` to turn it back into something of type `Eff eff a` to pass to `main`. You can do this by passing a continuation - `return` is probably good enough.